# In Django, restrict users to particular urls

Tags: django, django-urls, django-users, restrict

I have the following **urls** in my Django application:

```
path('rooms/<room_id>',views.home,name='home'),
```

**models**:

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    eid = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

**views**

```
def rooms(request):
    room = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).values()[0]['room_id']
    rooms = ChatRoom.objects.all().values()
    user = User.objects.filter(username=request.user)
    return render(request,'chat/rooms.html',{'rooms':rooms,'room_user':room})
```

Here <room_id> is variable i.e it depends on the eid of a Room model. A user can be a part of only one room. Therefore, the user can access only one <room_id>, let us say '4'. So, a user can access only rooms/4/. How can I restrict the user from entering into other URLs e.g. /rooms/5/ ?.

Comment: i think you need to define `OnetoMany` relationship between `User` and `ChatRoom` ?

Comment: simply create a many to many between `User` and `ChatRoom` and match the user with room and vice-versa, after that just do a checkup if user has a room assigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to make a `ForeignKey` from `UserProfile` to the `ChatRoom` model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # …
```

Then you can filter the rooms to only allow the one by the user with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def rooms(request):
    # the ChatRoom or None
    room = ChatRoom.objects.filter(userprofile__user=request.user).first()
    return render(request,'chat/rooms.html',{'room': room})
```

Since a user can only belong to one room as you say, it is thus a single room.

In your `home` method, we can use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) to raise a 404 in case the room is not the one of the user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def home(request, room_id):
    room = get_object_or_404(ChatRoom, eid=room_id, userprofile__user=request.user)
    # …
```

That being said, if a user can only be a member of one `ChatRoom`, then it makes not much sense to include this in the URL. You can simply obtain the chatroom as displayed above.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).